# use Rails' generator outside Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-generation

Rails has its own customizable [generator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html), how could I use them in my own non-rails project?

Or is there a gem that provides similar functionalities?

Answer (score 2):

I believe [Thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor) is what Rails uses internally for this type of task specifically

http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Actions#template-instance_method

Example https://github.com/wycats/thor/wiki/Generators